# Error starting Node.js app with PM2 and ts-node in production mode

Tags: node.js, typescript, pm2, production-environment, ts-node

I'm having trouble getting PM2 to work with ts-node. When I try to start my app using PM2, I get an error message saying that the ts-node interpreter is not available in the PATH.

I've tried installing ts-node globally and locally in my project, and I've also tried specifying the full path to the ts-node command in my `package.json` file, but none of these solutions have worked.

Here's the start script in my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/server.ts",
    "start:dev": "pm2 start --name backend C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ts-node    src/server.ts",
    "start:prod": "pm2 start --name backend \"npx ts-node src/server.ts\""
  },
```

And here's the error message I'm getting when I run `npm run start:dev`:

```
\[PM2\]\[ERROR\] Interpreter C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pm2\\node_modules.bin\\ts-node is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH. (type 'which C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pm2\\node_modules.bin\\ts-node' to double check.)
```

And here's the error message I'm getting when I run `npm run start:prod`:

```
> backend@1.0.0 start:prod2
> pm2 start --name backend "npx ts-node src/server.ts"

\[PM2\]\[ERROR\] Script not found: E:\\learning\\self_learning\\Projects\\nest\\backend\\npx ts-node src\\server.ts
```

What I tried:

I'm trying to start my Node.js app using PM2 in production mode. Here's the relevant part of my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
"start:dev": "pm2 start --name backend C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ts-node    src/server.ts"
},
```

What I expected to happen:

I expected PM2 to start my app using the `ts-node` interpreter and the `src/server.ts` file.

What actually resulted:

When I run `npm run start:dev`, I get the following error message:

```
\[PM2\]\[ERROR\] Interpreter C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pm2\\node_modules.bin\\ts-node is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH. (type 'which C:\\Users\\Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\pm2\\node_modules.bin\\ts-node' to double check.)
```

I've tried installing `ts-node` globally and locally in my project, and I've also tried specifying the full path to the `ts-node` command in my `package.json` file, but none of these solutions have worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever user environment is initiating the call to your app, you need that environment's `PATH` to include the folders in which you store `npx` and `ts-node`.

If you run `pm2 startup`, it should display another command for you to run as root that will apply the correct path to your /etc/init.d/pm2 script.

In Windows, you can download and run an installer that will configure pm2 as a service.

Run these lines with Administrator rights:

```
npm install -g pm2-windows-service

pm2-service-install -n PM2
```

This will ask several questions:

```
Perform environment setup (recommended)? Yes
Set PM2_HOME? Yes
PM2_HOME value?  c:\etc\.pm2\
Set PM2_SERVICE_SCRIPTS? No
Set PM2_SERVICE_PM2_DIR? [recommended] Yes
Specify the directory containing the pm2 version to be used by the service? 
    C:\USERS\<USER>\APPDATA\ROAMING\NPM\node_modules\pm2\index.js
```

Comment: I am trying to do that current now on Windows :( . So pm2 startup won't work

Comment: Ah, I should have caught that from the path.  There's a helpful article on https://blog.cloudboost.io/nodejs-pm2-startup-on-windows-db0906328d75

Comment: I think `npm install -g pm2-windows-service` followed by `pm2-service-install -n PM2` should fix up your path.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I got another error, 
```
> backend@1.0.0 start:prod
> pm2 start "npx ts-node src/server.ts"

connect EPERM //./pipe/rpc.sock
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=C:\Users\Pc\.pm2
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect EPERM //./pipe/rpc.sock
...
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the full paths to npx and tx-node to your user's classpath in the Control Panel (I search "path" in the start bar for this).

Comment: I want to deploy my project on a cloud service so I will use Linux and I will use ubuntu so I think that I should ignore running pm2 on Windows. What is your opinion?

Comment: I happily run Ubuntu under Windows.  Once configured you just run `bash` at a cmd prompt and have an environment very similar to a cloud-based server.

Comment: See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-in-the-microsoft-store-is-now-generally-available-on-windows-10-and-11/

Comment: I will try. Thank you!